# How can I reuse android db utilities in cordova project for android

Tags: android, cordova

I have developed an android application which uses ormlite as orm and have our own customised utility classes for db persistance . Now I'm porting my application to develop using cordova plugin. Is there any option to reuse the db utilities for my android specific cordova project? If yes, how?